# The local server and Netlify classified the answer page as a 405 not allowed page, even if the JavaScript is totally correct

Tags: javascript, html

We are building a basic form page. We have two pages called `index.html` and `answer.html`, and a JavaScript file called `script.js` in the same root folder.

Here's the small HTML and JavaScript codes:

- HTML:

```html
<form method="post" action="answer.html">

<label for="nome">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" />

<input type="submit" onclick="encaminhar()" />
</form>

<script src="script.js"></script>
```

```js
function encaminhar () {
  const nome = document.getElementById("nome").value
  const cpf = document.getElementById("cpf").value
  const logradouro = document.getElementById("logradouro").value
  const numero = document.getElementById("numero").value
  const telefone = document.getElementById("telefone").value

  if (nome != "" && cpf != "" && logradouro != "" && numero != "" && telefone != "") {
    window.location.href = "answer.html";
  }
  else {
    alert("Preencha os campos obrigatórios!")
  }
}
```

We received two error messages saying the page does not exist and, at the console, it said it is a 405 error. Netlify said `405 not allowed page`

Does that JavaScript seem correct for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405):

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 405 Method Not Allowed response status code indicates that the request method is known by the server but is not supported by the target resource.

`405 Method Not Allowed` occurs when for example you have `httpPost` request but you send `Get` request or other request that does not math with target.

I think `answer.html` is get request, so you need to change `<form method="post" action="answer.html">` to `<form method="get" action="answer.html">`